# How to get modern page view count using search or

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to get modern page view count by graph,search or powershell.
But dont find any proper documentation on this. has anyone tried this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Please run the following the PowerShell script:**

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll" 
 
function Get-SPOListView  
 {  
   param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]  
   [string]$Username,  
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]  
   $AdminPassword,  
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]  
   [string]$Url,  
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=4)]  
   [string]$ListTitle,  
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=5)]  
   [string]$TenantUrl  
   )  
  #Get the SharePoint List/Library.
   $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
   $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $Password)  
   $ll=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)  
   $ctx.load($ll)  
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
  #Get all items from the List/Library.
   $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()  
   $items = $ll.GetItems($qry)   
   $ctx.Load($items)  
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
   foreach($listItem in $items)  
   {  
     Write-Host "ID - " $listItem["ID"] "Title - " $listItem["Title"] "EncodedAbsUrl - " $listItem["FileRef"]     
     $fileurl = $TenantUrl+ $listItem["FileRef"]  
     #Using Search API - Create the instance of KeywordQuery and set the properties.
     $keywordQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery($ctx)   
     #Sample Query - To get the result of last year.
     $queryText="Path:" + $fileurl  
     $keywordQuery.QueryText = $queryText  
     $keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates=$false  
     $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ViewsLifeTime")  
     $keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers")  
     $keywordQuery.SortList.Add("ViewsLifeTime","Asc")   
     #Search API - Create the instance of SearchExecutor and get the result.
     $searchExecutor = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor($ctx)  
     $results = $searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery($keywordQuery)  
     $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  
     #Result Count  
     Write-Host $results.Value[0].ResultRows.Count  
     #CSV file location, to store the result  
     $exportlocation = "C:\Pages_ViewsCount.csv"  
     foreach($result in $results.Value[0].ResultRows)  
     {  
       $outputline='"'+$result["Title"]+'"'+","+'"'+$result["Path"]+'"'+","+$result["ViewsLifeTime"]+","+$result["ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers"]   
       Add-Content $exportlocation $outputline   
     }   
    
   }  
   }
  


# Insert the credentials along with Admin & Tenant URLs and Call above Function.      
#Enter Username here      
$Username="username@***.onmicrosoft.com"      
#Enter Password Here      
$Password=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString      
#URL of the site collection      
$Url= "site collection url"      
$ListTitle= "Site Pages"      
$TenantUrl= "Your tenant URL E.g. https://YourCompany.sharepoint.com"      
Get-SPOListView -Username $Username -AdminPassword $Password -Url $Url -ListTitle $ListTitle -TenantUrl $TenantUrl
```

More information, please refer to **[this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/office-365sharepoint-online-powershell-script-to-get-export-site-pages-viewslifetimeuniqueusers-viewslifetime-details)**.